# HTTP Packets, Whats Happening?

Tags: http, authentication, encryption, header, packet

basically, i was wiresharking packets on my PS3 while viewing Motorstorm Leaderboards. The leaderboards are sent to my ps3 in XML format but only after i have been authorised. So can someone please tell me what is happening between these three packets and how i could replicate it in a browser?

Packet 1 From my PS3 to Sony Servers

```
POST /ranking_view/func/get_player_rank HTTP/1.1
Host: ranking-view-a01.u0.np.community.playstation.net
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 213
Authorization: Digest username="c7y-ranking01", realm="c7y-ranking", nonce="2SpsV4WABAA=47a2b36030cd94de1190f6b9f05db1bd5584bc2a", uri="/ranking_view/func/get_player_rank", qop="auth", nc="00000001", cnonce="d4eb1eb60ab4efaea1476869d83a6e0b", response="96b55c6e79f84dd41b46eb66bed1c167"
Accept-Encoding: identity
User-Agent: PS3Community-agent/1.0.0 libhttp/1.0.0

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ranking platform="ps3" sv="3.15"><titleid>NPWR00012_00</titleid><board>7</board><jid>Panzerborn@a5.gb.np.playstation.net</jid><option message="false" info="false"/></ranking>
```

Packet 2 Sony Server Response to my PS3

```
Date: Fri, 26 Feb 2010 19:06:12 GMT
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="c7y-ranking", nonce="a3PFl4WABAA=6d375259676ec79641448a8032a795b8e12ccae4", algorithm=MD5, stale=true, qop="auth"
Content-Length: 401
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>401 Authorization Required</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Authorization Required</h1>
<p>This server could not verify that you
are authorized to access the document
requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
browser doesn't understand how to supply
the credentials required.</p>
</body></html>
```

Packet 3 PS3 response to Sony Servers last packet

```
POST /ranking_view/func/get_player_rank HTTP/1.1
Host: ranking-view-a01.u0.np.community.playstation.net
Connection: Keep-Alive
Authorization: Digest username="c7y-ranking01", realm="c7y-ranking", nonce="a3PFl4WABAA=6d375259676ec79641448a8032a795b8e12ccae4", uri="/ranking_view/func/get_player_rank", qop="auth", nc="00000001", cnonce="58869490a891002d8c56573496274a3a", response="ca3d6f252d4e398b8f751c201a3f8f08"
Accept-Encoding: identity
User-Agent: PS3Community-agent/1.0.0 libhttp/1.0.0

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ranking platform="ps3" sv="3.15"><titleid>NPWR00012_00</titleid><board>7</board><jid>Panzerborn@a5.gb.np.playstation.net</jid><option message="false" info="false"/></ranking>
```

I tried to replicate this in Firefox and tamper headers as well as in PHP cURL but im getting nowhere. I assume it is to do with the nonce, cnonce and responce variables that keep changing >< please help =)

Comment: For starters, they're not HTTP packets - "packet" is an IP-level concept. Those are full HTTP requests/responses.

Comment: oops, my bad then XD im not really used to all this packet sniffing ><

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nonce, cnonce and so on are related to [HTTP Digest Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication), which is an authentication mechanism that enables authentication without sending a password in plain text. So if you want to cheat in your PS3 game, you'll first have to hack that password out of the MD5 hash, I guess.

And it's not called HTTP *packets*, on layer 7 you would usually say request/response or similar.

Comment: i guess i didnt make it clear lol, im not trying to cheat. i just want to get the leaderboards of the game in xml format in a browser. those requests/responses ( :) ) only ask for the leaderboards. no scores are sent to the sony servers

Comment: You can try bruteforcing the digest password - it'll require you to do two MD5 operations per tested password (HA2 can be precalculated), which should mean you can test in the tens of millions of passwords per second.  If the password wasn't too long, you could conceivably find it this way.

Answer (score 3):

The nonce an `nonce` and  `cnonce` look like hash codes.

One possible defense mechanism against cheaters could be this:

```
def ps3client_send_score():
    score = "bazillion points"
    nonce = md5(score + "something you don't know about")
    send_to_server(score, nonce)
```

On the server side:

```
def get_client_score(score, nonce):
    if md5(score+"something you don't know about")==nonce:
        accept_score(score)
    else:
        reject_score_and_ban_the_fool_if_he_continues_this()
```

So unless you want to spend weeks trying to find the [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) deep in your game, forget it.

Comment: that would make alot of sence except those packets only recieve leaderboard data. so i dont see why theere would be alot of authentication. i mean the second motorstorm game doesnt even auth the leaderboards. i just want a way to scrape the leaderboards as there is no online one for the first motorstorm ><